# Does "chronological order" mean the most recent item comes first?

Tags: word-choice, list-order, sort-ordering

I want to say that a list is in chronological order. Does this implies that the most recent event comes first? Or do I have to mention that explicitly?

> This the list of papers in chronological order:
>   1) ... 2019
>   2) ... 2018

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In technical and common parlance, the phrase "chronological order" indicates that the items are in order of occurrence or creation, oldest first (being the first in the chronology).

So it's `[ 1997, 1998, 1999 ]` and **not** `[ 1999, 1998, 1997 ]`.

Ordering most recent first as in the example given in the question is called reverse chronological ordering or inverse chronological ordering.

Comment: Do include references in support. Good Luck.